# Delete All sended/error/unread PIN messages from Blackberry programmatically

Tags: blackberry, sms

I know how to simply erase the unread messages, but programatically i can't find any documentation on how to erase the delivered (cheked and with a D) or the not sended (X)

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the folder SENT dont save the SENT messages, 
You got to look for them in the OUTBOX folder, in there you can work with the type of the message and the status of them, so you can take decisions.